# problem with Times new roman font

Tags: fonts

i have this problem:

```
Package xepersian-mathsdigitspec Error: The font "Times New Roman" does not
(xepersian-mathsdigitspec)                contain U+06F0.
```

Comment: U+06F0 is EXTENDED ARABIC-INDIC DIGIT ZERO  Times New Roman is primarily a font for the Latin script.

Comment: tnx, so what should i do to solve it?

Comment: choose a font suitable for Persian, sorry I can't really suggest one, you can use whatever font your browser uses for the text you want to set.